# What is the range for the protections granted by an inverted Magic Circle?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect

According to the Magic Circle [spell description](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Magic%20Circle#content), you can reverse the spell while casting it so that a creature of a chosen type is trapped in the circle (without a saving throw) and creatures outside of it are given some pretty good buffs.

> When you cast this spell, you can elect to cause its magic to operate in the reverse direction, preventing a creature of the specified type from leaving the Cylinder and protecting Targets outside it.

Buffs are:

> - The creature has disadvantage on Attack rolls against Targets within the Cylinder.
> - Targets within the Cylinder can't be Charmed, Frightened, or possessed by the creature.

Although the circle itself has a range of 10-feet, the buffs do not have a range in the case of an inverted circle. Is it essentially just infinity then? This seems... exploitable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, the range of the buffs is effectively infinite. But they only work against the creature in the cylinder. Substituting the reversed benefits:

> - The creature can't willingly <strike>enter</strike> *leave* the cylinder by nonmagical means. If the creature tries to use teleportation or interplanar travel to do so, it must first succeed on a Charisma saving throw.
> - The creature has disadvantage on attack rolls against targets <strike>within</strike> *outside* the cylinder.
> - Targets <strike>within</strike> *outside* the cylinder can't be charmed, frightened, or possessed by the creature.

Narratively speaking, they're really limits on the creature, not buffs to everyone else. In terms of exploits, about the only one I can think of is trapping a creature to free everyone it currently has charmed, no matter where they are. Which is kind of cool, but hardly overpowered.

Comment: True. The exploit I was thinking of was mostly if aberrations were a valid creature type. Dimension door on top of a Elder Brain and cast it using a scroll would suppress the brain.

Comment: @RobRose As cool as that would be, the casting time of a minute is likely to present some problems...

Comment: @RobRose That's not an unintuitive exploit.  Locking a psychicly active brain within in a magic psychic-power-stopping prison sure seems like a reasonable way of suppressing it.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature!  Trapping a monster in a magic circle to block its influence is one of the classic uses of a magic circle.

Comment: @miniman But not if you used a ring of spell storing or a glyph of warding loaded with the spell, right?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Well, elder brains don't tend to move around, so glyph would be tricky, but the ring seems good.

Comment: Are you sure the charm/frighten/possess limitation means "cannot continue to be <condition>" rather than "cannot start to be <condition>"? Seems somewhat ambiguous to me.

Comment: @Vigil If I'm under the Charmed condition, imposed by an elder brain, I'm charmed by it. Which I can't be if said elder brain is in a magic circle.